# How to use die() in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

In Smarty we can use `var_dump()` but I can't use `die()`. How to do it?

```
{$something|@var_dump}
```

or

```
{var_dump($something)}
```

Comment: have you tried `exit();`

Comment: A template engine should not be able to do a die!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only by add Smarty plugin:

```
function smarty_function_die()
{
    die();
}
```

and in template:
`{die}`

PS I don't even mention about `{php}die();{/php}`